# TextView animation - fade in, wait, fade out automatically with some time Duration

Tags: android, animation, textview, fadein, fadeout

I have one Textview field. i want to display it as a fadeIn FadeOut animation with certain period of time with repeat motion. How to do that.Any help please welcome.I read dozen of solution bt not find helpfull. Thanks.....In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace `yourTextView` with your `textview`. Change the animation duration as required

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        yourTextView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Glad to know. Consider accepting my answer and an upvote will help